# Wifi not Enabled at login screen

Tags: networking, wireless

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on an old Thinkpad. Usually wifi is Enabled automatically after boot-up. A notification pops up saying that wifi networks are available. After entering my password the machine connects as intended to my wifi.That is the way I want it. 
The other day I connected an Ethernet cable to see how speed was affected. After removing the cable I could then connect manually back to my wifi. However, ever since then wifi in not automatically enabled at login. I have had to manually connect to the wifi.
How can I get back to automatically enabling wifi at start-up? I have looked at the various settings but nothing looks wrong.
Thanks for any advice on this issue!

Update:
Well...the problem described above has gone away, without any conscious act on my part. It's a mystery to me.I did notice that this seemed to be simultaneous with an unassociated problem with the my-weather-indicator app, that I had set to open automatically after login. I have no idea whether this was entirely coincidental or whether they were in some way technically connected. I am inclined to close my question but it would be better if someone could throw some light on this development.

Comment: Well...the problem has gone away, without any conscious act on my part. It's a mystery to me.I did notice that this seemed to be simultanous with an unassociated problem with the my-weather-indictor app, that I had to open automatically after login. I have no idea whether this was entirely coincidental or whether they were in some way technically connected.